# Is it possible to automatically list open source libraries and their licenses?

Tags: java, android

I want to display a list of **all open source libraries and their licenses in my Android app**, just like Google Play. But there are too many libraries in my app, is there anyway to **automatically** maintain this list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this [library](https://github.com/mikepenz/AboutLibraries). Which automatically creates a fragment/activity with your libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your information. Its basic idea is likely to maintain a known database of libraries, which is **obviously incomplete and maybe slow, but still a solution**.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [this](https://github.com/hierynomus/license-gradle-plugin) - if you build your project using gradle you can include this plugin to manage your licenses.

From the doc: "This plugin will also report on the licenses of your dependencies."

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it seems only affects source(generate source header), while what I'm looking for is a runtime list.

Comment: @Muyangmin Did you find a proper way of achieving this at runtime while you worked on this issue 5 years ago?